# Errno 13 when trying to open file c++

Tags: c++

I've been working on this for a while, and I'm out of ideas. I've been trying to open and write to a file, but nothing's happening. I've been getting errno 13, but I have full permissions in the directory the file is in. If anyone has any ideas what's going on, I'd appreciate it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt", std::ios::out);
  std::cout << errno << std::endl;
  myfile << "test";
  myfile.close ();
  return 0;
}
```

I've also tried using fopen, but I didn't have any luck with that either.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Make sure you are in a directory that is **writable** when you run it. It looks like you are trying to create `"example.txt"` in a direction where you lack write permission.

Comment: Also, rather than just outputting `errno`, you should test `if (!myfile.is_open()) { std::cerr << errno << std::endl; return 1; }` (**note:** when writing error output, use `std::cerr`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the deal was, but I got it working by moving it to a different directory. Guess it was a permissions error, but for some reason windows was saying I had permission to write to the directory.

Comment: Yep, that was the only thing that made sense `:)`